# authentication failed starting psql

Tags: postgresql

After installing postgres, I tried to start psql on my VPS and got an authentication failure

```
~$ psql
Password: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "michael"
```

I went back to my install instructions, which had me set my password this way

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';
```

I tried to do that again but wasn't able to login:

```
 sudo -u postgres psql template1
Password: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I'm thinking that I either forgot the password, or, more likely, did this step wrong. The instructions told me, in sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf,  to change

```
local all postgres
```

to

```
local all postgres md5
```

so in the following code, I replaced both instances of `peer` with `md5`

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Is there a way that I can recover or change my password now that I'm locked out?

Update

when trying to login, authentication fails whether I use user postgres or michael

```
 sudo -u michael psql template
Password: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "michael"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/514337/configuring-md5-authentication-in-postgres

Comment: @DeerHunter it's not a duplicate, although there is some overlap. This question is about being locked out, while the other question is about how to configure md5. It might be that faulty configuration of md5 is responsible for me being locked out, which is why I mentioned it here, but the substance of the questions is entirely different (imho).

Comment: The takeaway part is the same, though: you have to stop what you are doing and read the docs. A cavalry charge doesn't always help.

Comment: @DeerHunter no, there I disagree. Almost every question on this site and every stack exchange site could be answered by 'reading the docs.' Also, I obviously misunderstood the docs in the other question (otherwise the md5 wouldn't be set incorrectly). If you don't want to answer the question, that's fine, but your logic is in error regarding the 'duplicate.' Just because the 'takeaway' as you undestand it is the same, doesn't make the question the same.

Comment: @Michael This question is not a duplicate, but you ***REALLY*** need to stop and read the docs. [ALL of the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/), not just some random tutorials on the internet. You've posted two questions in three hours, both of which you wouldn't be asking if you'd taken the time to read and understand the Postgres documentation. Server Fault is [a site for professionals](http://serverfault.com/about), and professionals *read the documentation*.

Comment: @voretag7 the docs are for people who know how to use the system, not ideal for learners.  I still read the docs but the volume of information is very difficult to remember, because I don't know at the time of reading what I'll need to remember at setup time, so it's a continual back-and-forth between docs and trial-and-error. I see this site is for professionals, but that's a vague term. I'm running my own server/business (or at least trying to) so i guess it makes me a professional in a way even if I'm not a professional by experience and skill. If I should ask Qs somewhere else, let me know

Comment: It doesn't help that you're trying to connect to `template`, which doesn't usually exist, not the default `tempate1` or `postgres` databases. If you've locked yourself out, change authentication back to `peer` for `local` connections and set the correct password with `ALTER USER`.

Comment: @Michael There's an introductory PostgreSQL tutorial in the PostgreSQL docs, and the documentation for your PostgreSQL packages contain installation-specific details. In your case since you're on Ubuntu I'd say that'll be https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL . Start reading there, and in `/usr/share/doc/postgres*/README.Debian*` where all the install-specific details are recorded. Yes, that could be more obvious, but ... suggestions on *how we can make it more obvious* given that the PostgreSQL team don't control how Ubuntu package PostgreSQL?

Comment: @CraigRinger ok, thanks, I'm trying to connect to template because those are the instructions i was given to install on ubuntu by my vps provider http://hendrelouw73.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/how-to-install-postgresql-9-1-on-ubuntu-13-04-linux/

Comment: @Michael Er, no, those instructions refer to the default database template called `template1`.

Comment: @craigRinger are you telling me Step 3 in that blog post is not telling me to access or connect to (not sure of terminology) to template to configure password:  `STEP 3: CONFIGURE YOUR POSTGRESQL PASSWORD

1
2
3
sudo -u postgres psql template1
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';`

Comment: @CraigRinger anyways, I guess I misuderstood but thanks for referring me to the ubuntu tutorial for postgresql

Comment: @CraigRinger can you explain what this is if it's not setting password as the blog advises? should I do it?  `sudo -u postgres psql template1
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';`

Comment: @Michael It says `template1` not `template`. *nowhere* in that blog post does it say `template`. As for the password setting that looks perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually set passwords on these database accounts prior to enabling MD5 password authentication?

If you haven't set a password (or you have but you don't remember them) you can reset the passwords by setting the authentication type to `trust` in [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), logging in as your Postgres superuser account, and changing the passwords with the [`ALTER USER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-alteruser.html) command.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the type to `trust` from `md5` but when I run this command `sudo -u postgres psql template1` I still get password auth failed for user postgres. According to my instructions, I need to run that command to do `alter user` to change the password

Comment: @Michael You probably didn't restart PostgreSQL after making the change, or you did something else wrong. **read the documentation**, or at least the PostgreSQL tutorials. Since you're apparently on Ubuntu, start with Ubuntu's guide on the default Ubuntu install of PostgreSQL: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL